# Is there any doc which explains the behaviour of Cassandra CDC internal details?

Tags: cassandra

I was working on POC where I need to parse Cassandra CDC logs and use it for some purpose. In latest Cassandra version 4.1 Cassandra CDC contains _cdc.idx file which points to durable writes in CommitLog. Is .idx file is per CommitLog file? Is there 1-1 correspondence? How does it work?

I was trying out some scenarios and found following things:

1. Sometimes only idx file is present and no CommitLog is there.

```
[root@xxx cdc_raw]# ls
CommitLog-7-1682328691317_cdc.idx
```

2. Sometimes multiple CommitLog files are there and single idx file is there.

```
[root@xxx cdc_raw]# ls
CommitLog-7-1682328691317_cdc.idx  CommitLog-7-1682486101658.log  CommitLog-7-1682492980412.log
CommitLog-7-1682328691319.log      CommitLog-7-1682486101659.log  CommitLog-7-1682492980413.log
```

To which file this idx file offset points to? How does it work?
I tried to search for specific answer on many sites including following
[https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/operating/cdc.html#:~:text=Change%20data%20capture%20(CDC)%20provides,the%20table%20or%20altering%20it%20](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/operating/cdc.html#:%7E:text=Change%20data%20capture%20(CDC)%20provides,the%20table%20or%20altering%20it%20))
but couldn't figure out the one. Can somebody make me understand about idx-commitlog relation in case of Cassandra CDC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each CDC index file (`*_cdc.idx`) maps to a corresponding commitlog segment.

The format for the filenames are:

- commitlog - `"CommitLog" + version + segment_id + ".log"`
- index - `"CommitLog" + version + segment_id + "_cdc.idx"`

So the file `CommitLog-7-1682328691317_cdc.idx` (which has segment ID `1682328691317`) is the index for commitlog `CommitLog-7-1682328691317.log`.

Unfortunately there isn't a document that explains all the details. I have to confess that I haven't spent much time on the CDC feature so I had to do some research myself.

I would recommend having a look at [CASSANDRA-8844](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8844) which is the equivalent design document for CDC and [CASSANDRA-12148](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-12148) which discusses the implementation of the CDC index files.

I also spent some time looking at the code to understand how it works.

[`CommitLogDescriptor.java`](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-4.1/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/commitlog/CommitLogDescriptor.java#L230-L252) shows the filename convention for the segments and index files.

For details of what is stored in the index files, have a look at [`CommitLogSegment.writeCDCIndexFile()`](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-4.1/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/commitlog/CommitLogSegment.java#L389-L408). Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your pointers!! I will check them.I also had similar understanding that each idx file maps to commitlog segmemt. I was expecting CommitLog-7-1682328691317.log in cdc_raw directory along with idx file. But that is not the case. That segment was not there. Also for other case I was expecting idx files for all commitlog segments, but those idx files were not there.

Answer (score 0):

A *.idx file should only be being created when a CDC mutation has been fsynced into a commitlog segment, which shouldn't be being auto-deleted with a CDC mutation present and which shouldn't therefore be missing.  I don't see a bug report for the missing *.log file at issues.apache.org/jira/projects/CASSANDRA/issues .  If you can reproduce the missing *.log file, and haven't caused that yourself, you should report a bug.